# Wait for the result of an INotifyTaskCompletion property in an awaitable manner?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, async-await, inotifytaskcompletion

I have a WinRT app that uses the **Nito.AsyncEx** library.  I have a property that implements *INotifyTaskCompletion*.  It works great for XAML items that data bind to the property.  I now find myself in a situation where I need to wait for the property to have a non-null result from a code-behind context. Currently I am using an *async* method that loops with a Task.Delay() statement until the property Result is non-null.  Is there a more efficient way to do this, preferably something that supports a time-out and a way to check for a time-out condition?

*Note, the code to retrieve the URL that fulfills the INotifyTaskCompletion property is fired off from the ViewModel's constructor.*

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Waits for the rate and review URL to show up or until the time-out limit expires.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="timeoutSecs">The number of seconds to wait before giving up.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns the rate & review URL if it was retrieved, NULL if the request timed-out</returns>
    async private Task<string> WaitForRateAndReviewUrlAsync(int timeoutSecs = 30)
    {
        DateTime dtStart = DateTime.Now;
        bool bIsTimedOut = false;

        if (timeoutSecs < 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("The time-out value is negative.");

        while (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(GetMainViewModel.RateAndReviewURL.Result) && !bIsTimedOut )
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);

            bIsTimedOut = (DateTime.Now - dtStart).TotalSeconds >= timeoutSecs;
        } // while()

        return GetMainViewModel.RateAndReviewURL.Result;
    }
```

Comment: If you have control of the view model why don't you do a check there and fire off an event kind of the way EventAggregator works. Then in your code behind you know when the value has changed based on your set of rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`INotifyTaskCompletion` exposes the task that it wraps, as the `Task` property.

So, your code can do this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Waits for the rate and review URL to show up or until the time-out limit expires.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="timeoutSecs">The number of seconds to wait before giving up.</param>
/// <returns>Returns the rate & review URL if it was retrieved, NULL if the request timed-out</returns>
async private Task<string> WaitForRateAndReviewUrlAsync(int timeoutSecs = 30)
{
  if (timeoutSecs < 0)
    throw new ArgumentException("The time-out value is negative.");
  var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutSecs));
  var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(timeoutTask, GetMainViewModel.RateAndReviewURL.Task);
  if (completedTask == timeoutTask)
    return null;
  return GetMainViewModel.RateAndReviewURL.Result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen.  Nito.AsyncEx is a great library.

Comment: What is the easiest way to work a cancellation token into the mix to cancel both tasks if desired?

Comment: You'd want to pass the token into your `async` method; `Task.Delay` has an overload that also takes a token.

Comment: Thanks, good tip.  I find myself rewriting a lot of my async methods to change the embedded awaitable operations in the method to make use of cancellation tokens.  I had a nice real life occurrence of the dangers of not doing so today.

Answer (score 2):

Just `await` the task, rather than synchronously waiting for the task to complete, and then waiting for some period of time before checking again:

```
var result = await GetMainViewModel.RateAndReviewURL;

while(result != null)
{
    result = await GetMainViewModel.RateAndReviewURL;
}

return result;
```